# Why 5 RUs are charged for Write operations in single region? Will same applies for any cosmosdb API I choose?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB charges 1 RU for 1 KB read which is understood but want to learn more on why 5 RUs are charged for 1KB Write?

Is it same 5 RUs for writes on all models like SQL API, MongoAPI, KV Store, Cassandra API and Gremlin API?

Also can I call cassandra or mongodb in cosmosdb directly via client libraries?

Comment: We started using cosmosdb and started out with the cassandra api. I thought the writes were 2 RUs per KB, not 5, but maybe that's not true. Anyway, the writes are more expensive due to the replication components I believe. Either way, it is what it is and it's good to know up front. As for using client libraries, I believe you can use anything that connects to cassandra. For example, I believe you can even use cqlsh to connect to the cassandra api for cosmosdb. We have since changed to use their "SQL" (documentdb) instead of cassandra as it's more flexible.

Comment: You want to look at this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim. But it will be a good idea to know better how the charges are charged against the read/write so that we can have better way of budget utilisation

Comment: This document is fairly recent (only a few months old): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/key-value-store-cost. Should give you your cost numbers